# Do I need to use objcopy before flashing my ARM microcontroller with OpenOCD?

Tags: arm, elf, objcopy, openocd

"Normal" ARM cross-compilation for ARM microncontrollers generally consists of three or four steps:

1. Use an assembler to assemble the startup code (if it is assembly) into an object file
2. Use a compiler to compile any source code into object files
3. Use a linker to link the object files into an .elf file
4. Use objcopy to convert the .elf file into a .hex file
5. Flash the .hex file

It is step #4 that I am unsure about. In the documentation for OpenOCD's `flash write_image` command, it states:

> The file [type] can be specified explicitly as bin (binary), ihex (Intel hex), elf (ELF file), s19 (Motorola s19). mem, or builder.

It is clear that OpenOCD supports elf files, but I don't know what this actually means. Is this only supported on some targets? Must the JTAG/SWD adapter provide some sort of objcopy-like functionality for this to work? Is it simply a holdover from the days when OpenOCD did not yet support elf files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

file formats that include address and data like elf, ihex, srec are good to use, I use elf primarily.  .bin file doesnt carry the address so you 1) have to specify the starting address 2) objcopy pads gaps between defined areas which can create problems as well as take more loading time, etc.

Using a .bin leaves room for human error on the address.  Unfortunately I have had situations where a combination of .elf and openocd will load a the wrong address or at least print the wrong address when loading.

I use .elf files wherever possible.  .hex or .srec if the utility does not support elf but supports ihex or srec.  And .bin for example when using x/y/zmodem loaders.

I would assume that openocd is layered, that there is a front end that reads the files and by the time it gets to the backend, the jtag or whatever the backend doesnt know what kind of file the data originated from.  I dont know for a fact but assume...

Comment: swd vs jtag, my understanding is swd is a serial form of jtag, same sorts if not same commands just transmitted back and forth using less pins.

Comment: So, given that the OpenOCD `flash write_image` command explicitly says it supports elf files, it should work? It doesn't depend on the microcontroller, or the flash layout, or the compiler, or...?

Comment: well naturally the binary you are loading should be something you really want to write to the device of course, dont want to try to load code for the wrong processor.  if you are able to load a raw .bin file using that command (some/many of the supported devices openocd doesnt know how to write to their flash) then a .elf or .hex or whatever should work fine.  I use load_image myself 99% of the time (and elfs 99.9999999% of the time) and write to the flash only on occasion (and use elf files there as well).

Comment: now flash is generally one linear chunk of address space, by using a .bin you have to specify the address but you can easily see from the size of the .bin file how much data is being loaded, where the .elf file is loaded with lots of extra stuff and allows for multiple memory areas, I would hope the flash write_image gives a warning/error if the flash fails or if it is possible for openocd to know an portion of the image is going to ram not flash.

Comment: My experience is so limited and my projects so simple that it wouldn't prove much...